# Set a global state in react and use it by all components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React and I am currently working on a requirement based on SPFx which uses React. Here is my question-

I have four components- A, B , C and D.

1. The user searches for a list of names in component A which makes up screen 1 and upon clicking of a name, navigates to screen 2.
2. B, C and D components are part of a left navigation bar which make up screen 2.
3. B, C and D components need to receive the name that is clicked in component A and perform some operation like data retrieval specific to the clicked name.

Hence A updates the global variable upon clicking where as B, C, D components use it to perform operations.

In order to do this, I found out that we could use React Context, Redux or Local Storage. I am skeptical to use local storage due to security reasons. I cant quite put a finger on React Context or Redux in order to achieve this. Kindly help.

Comment: you may send` name/id ` while navigating to the second screen through the navigation and can receive and use it on the second screen.

Comment: The second screen is made up of 3 components snd may increase at a later point of time. If I had just 1, I would have done this. All 3 components should access the same variable

Comment: Ok use React Context it is great !! Others too but I'm a fan boy. Now follow at least one tutorial on the subject to learn how to use it, then try by yourself and come back with a starting solution and a real problem.

Comment: use React Context

Comment: I'd start with the React Context API first for such a light app state use case. React-redux is built using the Context API and applies the Redux state management pattern, so once you are more comfortable with how a Context works and how data flows through your app it is a *relatively* small step into implementing redux if/when your state management needs grow.

Comment: Since you're new to React I wouldn't recommend learning Redux just yet. Instead, learn React Context API.